# PHP Class __Constructor parameters are NULL once function call happened

Tags: php, function, constructor, null

After all, searching enough in SO I couldn't find out a most generic with best practice solution for **PHP __constructor with multiple parameter into a class function**

I am trying to define a function inside a PHP class. Where I will be using this function multiple times through a simple function call. Where the function will be having 2 or more parameters.

When I do a function call by passing the parameter, it's just **NULL** when it reaches the __constructor.

1. Why it's NULL?

Also, note that there are objects nested inside the function `addFruitCheckBox`.

1. What I am doing wrong?
2. I may also wanted to pass a function call instead of `$this->addFruitCheckBoxItemName` sometimes.

There are lot of specific problems and solutions in SO. However, I believe this generic question will help me and all, for **passing mulitple parameter into __constructor function in a PHP class**

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$_GET['SELECTEDTABNAME'] = 'properties';

/* all include files that are involved in function call within a function will be declared here */

class AddFruitController
{

    protected $addFruitCheckBoxItemName;
    protected $addFruitCheckBoxLabel;
    protected $addFruitMenuItemName;
    protected $addFruitChoiceItemName;
    protected $addFruitTimeItemName;
    public $trustedFruits;
    public $trustedFruitsModel;
    public $trustedFruitsSpeed;
    public $addNewFruit;
    public $additionalTub;
    public $chooseParent;
    public $FruitDown;
    public $FruitSell;
    public $timeTitle;
    public $addFruitbutton;

    public function __construct($addFruitCheckBoxItemName, $addFruitCheckBoxLabel, $addFruitMenuItemName, $addFruitTimeItemName)
    {
        global $interpreterMan, $fetchSeedForSapling;

        // var_dump($this->addFruitCheckBoxLabel);
        // var_dump($this->addFruitCheckBoxItemName);

        $this->trustedFruits = $interpreterMan("Trusted Fruits");
        $this->trustedFruitsModel = $interpreterMan("Model");
        $this->trustedFruitsSpeed = $interpreterMan("Speed");
        $this->addNewFruit = $interpreterMan("New Fruit");
        $this->additionalTub = $interpreterMan("Additional Options");
        $this->chooseParent = $interpreterMan("Choose Parent");
        $this->FruitDown = $interpreterMan("Download Schedule");
        $this->FruitSell = $interpreterMan("Install Schedule");
        $this->timeTitle = $interpreterMan("Time");
        $this->addFruitbutton = $interpreterMan("Add Fruit(s)");

        $this->addFruitCheckBoxItemName = $addFruitCheckBoxItemName;
        $this->addFruitCheckBoxLabel = $addFruitCheckBoxLabel;
        $this->addFruitMenuItemName = $addFruitMenuItemName;
        $this->addFruitChoiceItemName = $addFruitChoiceItemName;
        var_dump($addFruitChoiceItemName);
        $this->addFruitTimeItemName = $addFruitTimeItemName;

    }

    public function addFruitMenu()
    {
        global $interpreterMan;

        $theWidfetch = new FruitMenu();
        $theWidfetch->AssignAddJsCode(false);
        $theWidfetch->AssignChoiceOrder(array($interpreterMan("English")));
        $theWidfetch->AssignChoiceText(array($interpreterMan("English") => $interpreterMan("English")));
        $theWidfetch->AssignGroupHeader($this->addFruitMenuItemName);
        $theWidfetch->AssignItemName($this->addFruitMenuItemName);
        $theWidfetch->AssignSaveLocation($this->addFruitMenuItemName);
        $theWidfetch->AssignValueToUse("ipad");
        $theWidfetch->WaterPath(true, true);
    }

    public function addFruitChoiceTable()
    {
        global $fetchSeedForSapling, $interpreterMan;
        $weekChoiceSelection = new FruitChoiceTable();
        $weekChoiceSelection->AssignAddJsCode(false);
        $weekChoiceSelection->AssignChoiceOrder(
            array("sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat"));
        $weekChoiceSelection->AssignChoiceText(array(
            "sun" => $interpreterMan("SUN"),
            "mon" => $interpreterMan("MON"),
            "tue" => $interpreterMan("TUE"),
            "wed" => $interpreterMan("WED"),
            "thu" => $interpreterMan("THU"),
            "fri" => $interpreterMan("FRI"),
            "sat" => $interpreterMan("SAT"),
        ));
        var_dump($weekChoiceSelection->AssignGroupHeader($this->addFruitChoiceItemName));
        $weekChoiceSelection->AssignItemName("Weekday");
        $weekChoiceSelection->AssignNumColumns(7);
        $weekChoiceSelection->AssignValueToUse($fetchSeedForSapling("dayOfWeek"));
        $weekChoiceSelection->WaterPath(true, true);
    }

    public function addFruitTime()
    {
        global $fetchSeedForSapling;
        $FruitTimeSelect = new FruitTime();
        $FruitTimeSelect->AssignGroupHeader($addFruitTimeItemName);
        $FruitTimeSelect->AssignItemName($addFruitTimeItemName);
        $FruitTimeSelect->AssignValueToUse($fetchSeedForSapling("minuteOfDay"));
        $FruitTimeSelect->WaterPath(true, true);
    }

    public function addFruitCheckBox()
    {
        global $fetchSeedForSapling;
        $addFruitCheckBoxObj = new FruitCheckbox();
        $addFruitCheckBoxObj->AssignAddJsCode(false);
        $addFruitCheckBoxObj->AssignCheckboxLabel($this->addFruitCheckBoxLabel);
        $addFruitCheckBoxObj->AssignItemName($this->addFruitCheckBoxItemName);
        $addFruitCheckBoxObj->AssignSaveLocation("somejob");
        $addFruitCheckBoxObj->AssignValueToUse($fetchSeedForSapling("somejob"));
        $addFruitCheckBoxObj->WaterPath(true, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not even valid PHP.

Comment: I can show you reference in same SO, where they have followed the method and has got upvotes too. For passing parameters into class name. @JonStirling

Comment: You can pass as many arguments as you want into the constructor, but if the constructor doesn't do anything with them, nothing magical is going to happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating such complex objects, I suggest you to use [**Builder Design Pattern**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/builder_pattern.htm) instead of assigning properties dynamically and directly.

**Note:** For better, you can add a layer of `interface` which `Builder` classes will `implement`. And you can have multiple `Builder` classes which generate different complex objects as per different use cases. Hope [**this**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/522531afc2bab516185497600edafb50b1cf4f3b) make sense.

[**Try this code snippet here**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/03a6fab76af3687f04f735379846cc875f08dba7)

```
<?php

class Builder {
    public static function getMyClass($a, $b, $c) {
        $myClass = MyClass::getInstance();
        $myClass->setA($a);
        $myClass->setB($b);
        return $myClass;
    }
}
class MyClass {
    protected $a=0;
    protected $b=0;

    public static function getInstance() {
        $myClass = new MyClass();
        return $myClass;
    }

    function setA($a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    function setB($b) {
        $this->b = $b;
    }
}

$myClass = Builder::getMyClass("a", "b", "c");
print_r($myClass);
```

**Explanation:** In the above mentioned code we have a `Builder` class which is responsible for building such complex objects.

But still if you are still more towards dynamic assignment approach which nobody recommends, you can see this [post](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php#114159)

Comment: `$addFruitPage = new AddFruitController $addFruitPage->addFruitCheckBox("cbox1") $addFruitPage->addFruitTextBox("hobbit")  $addFruitPage->addFruitTextArea("pineapple")` <- **Is this legal and a good practice?** `global $translateFruitName, $getFruitConfigAttribute; var_dump($this->addFruitCheckBoxItemName); var_dump(addFruitCheckBoxLabel);` If I print this, it's showing NULL, why is that?

Comment: @CommonMan Yes because in constructor you are sending some parameters but you are not receiving those in constructor and secondly `addFruitTextArea` is not returning anything. And the way you are using it, it perfectly okay.

Comment: but I am getting a notice at the `__contructor` parameter at insitantiation of a class object. `Missing argument 1 for AddFruitController::__construct(), called in` like wise 5 notice with missing argument 5.

Comment: @CommonMan are you using my post's code or your code ?

Comment: I am using my code @Sahil. I am using 5 parameters too for 5 different functions inside `AddFruitController` class.

Comment: @CommonMan Can you please update your code which you are currently using, so that i can help you out.

Comment: I have posted the entire code that I am trying to do. Where even if I tried using `protected` on `var_dump($weekChoiceSelection->AssignGroupHeader($this->addFruitChoiceItemName));` `var_dump($addFruitChoiceItemName);` were showing **NULL**. Why it's showing NULL despite of using @geggleto idea, where for one public function it's working good and for the other public function `addFruitChoiceTable` it's NOT working.

Comment: You should define your constructor like this `public function __construct($addFruitCheckBoxItemName="", $addFruitCheckBoxLabel="", $addFruitMenuItemName="", $addFruitTimeItemName="")` to have these variable some default value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142693/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-common-man).

Comment: I have accepted the answer based on the changes you supported me through chat! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

```
class MyClass {
    protected $a1;
    protected $a2;
    protected $a3;

    public function __construct($a1, $a2, $a3) {
        $this->a1 = $a1;
        $this->a2 = $a2;
        $this->a3 = $a3;
    }
}
```

Comment: but how many parameters you will pass like that in `__constructor` class. If I have 30 parameters you wanted me to pass like that? Also I am going to have multiple function inside the `class`. I may not use all functions at same time. So it will be a `NULL` parameter which could throw a notice. You wated me to do that?

Comment: If you want to pass a large number of parameters, then `get_func_args()` or the splat operator (`...`) may be useful

Comment: Or an assoc array!